# Touch управление в игре

Tags: unity3d

Как реализовать управление чтобы объект двигался за пальцем?

Comment: Мало информации). Объясните подробнее что вы хотите получить. Какая у вас игра 2D или 3D. В общем-то задача не сложная, все решается при помощи простенького скрипта, но опять же, тач штука такая... может быть несколько касаний, вам требуется чтобы обрабатывалось только одно первое касание?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы обрабатывались 1 касание. Игра 3D с камерой сверху, нужно чтобы по осям x и y двигался объект

Comment: *x и z. По координатам

Answer (score -1):

Тач возвращает координату в пикселях. Все что нужно перевести ее в мировые координаты. Если вы знаете на каком удалении у вас от объекта камера, то спокойно переводим точку экрана в мировые координаты [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

Я обычно делаю в таких случаях следующим образом. Создаю пустой объект, он будет у нас целью куда нам надо переместиться. Когда ловим тач высчитываем позицию в которой у нас должен оказаться объект и перемещаем в эту точку нашу объект-цель. А дальше уже заставляем двигаться к цели. Если надо просто чтобы объект переместился в заданную точку без логики по кратчайшему пути, то использую такой скрипт:

```
public class FollowMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target = null;
    public bool Smoothing = true;
    public float TimeMoving = 0.5f;
    public Vector3 Scale = Vector3.one;
    // Use this for initialization

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        /*if (Target)
        {
            transform.position = Target.position;
            transform.rotation = Target.rotation;
        }*/
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Target != null)
        {

            if (Smoothing)
            {
                transform.position += ReScale(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, Target.position, Time.deltaTime / TimeMoving) - transform.position);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Target.rotation, Time.deltaTime / TimeMoving);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += ReScale(Target.position - transform.position);
                transform.rotation = Target.rotation;

            }


        }

    }

    private Vector3 ReScale(Vector3 change)
    {
        change.Scale(Scale);
        return change;
    }
}
```